# Writing netcdf after running xarray.dataset.reindex to fill gaps in a time series fails due to memory allocation error

Tags: out-of-memory, netcdf, python-xarray, grib

## Problem Summary

I am attempting to convert a.grib2 file representing a single day's worth of gridded radar rainfall data spanning the continental US, into a netcdf. When a .grib2 is missing timesteps, I am attempting to fill them in with NA values using `xarray.Dataset.reindex` before running `xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf`. However, after I've reindexed the dataset, the script fails due to a memory allocation error. It succeeds if I don't reindex. One clue could be in the fact that the dataset chunks are set to `(70, 3500, 7000)`, but when `ds.to_netcdf` is called, the script fails because it's attempting to load a chunk with dimensions `(210, 3500, 7000)`.

## Accessing Full Reproducible Example

The code and data to reproduce my results can be downloaded from [this Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w31kpx2u13ymg3j/AAB6Gzf6fqetgk1FViRbKm2Ba?dl=0). The code is also shown below followed by the outputs. Potentially relevant OS and environment information are shown below as well.

## Code

```py
#%% Import libraries
import time
start_time = time.time()
import xarray as xr
import cfgrib
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import dask
dask.config.set(**{'array.slicing.split_large_chunks': False}) # to silence warnings of loading large slice into memory
dask.config.set(scheduler='synchronous') # this forces single threaded computations (netcdfs can only be written serially)
#%% parameters
chnk_sz = "7000MB"
fl_out_nc = "out_netcdfs/20010101.nc"
fldr_in_grib = "in_gribs/20010101.grib2"

#%% loading and exporting dataset
ds = xr.open_dataset(fldr_in_grib, engine="cfgrib", chunks={"time":chnk_sz},
                    backend_kwargs={'indexpath': ''})

# reindex
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2001-01-01')
tstep = pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:05:00')
new_index = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=start_date + pd.Timedelta(1, "day"),\
                                    freq=tstep, inclusive='left')

ds = ds.reindex(indexers={"time":new_index})
ds = ds.unify_chunks()
ds = ds.chunk(chunks={'time':chnk_sz})

print("######## INSPECTING DATASET PRIOR TO WRITING TO NETCDF ########")
print(ds)
print(' ')
print("######## ERROR MESSAGE ########")
ds.to_netcdf(fl_out_nc, encoding= {"unknown":{"zlib":True}})
```

## Outputs

```
######## INSPECTING DATASET PRIOR TO WRITING TO NETCDF ########
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (time: 288, latitude: 3500, longitude: 7000)
Coordinates:
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 2001-01-01 ... 2001-01-01T23:55:00
  * latitude    (latitude) float64 54.99 54.98 54.98 54.97 ... 20.03 20.02 20.01
  * longitude   (longitude) float64 230.0 230.0 230.0 ... 300.0 300.0 300.0
    step        timedelta64[ns] ...
    surface     float64 ...
    valid_time  (time) datetime64[ns] dask.array<chunksize=(288,), meta=np.ndarray>
Data variables:
    unknown     (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(70, 3500, 7000), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            2
    GRIB_centre:             161
    GRIB_centreDescription:  161
    GRIB_subCentre:          0
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             161
    history:                 2022-09-10T14:50 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0.9.1...
 
######## ERROR MESSAGE ########
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\Dropbox\_Sharing\reprex\2022-9-9_writing_ncdf_fails\reprex\exporting_netcdfs_reduced.py in <cell line: 22>()
     160 print(' ')
     161 print("######## ERROR MESSAGE ########")
---> 162 ds.to_netcdf(fl_out_nc, encoding= {"unknown":{"zlib":True}})

File c:\Users\Daniel\anaconda3\envs\weather_gen_3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py:1882, in Dataset.to_netcdf(self, path, mode, format, group, engine, encoding, unlimited_dims, compute, invalid_netcdf)
   1879     encoding = {}
   1880 from ..backends.api import to_netcdf
-> 1882 return to_netcdf(  # type: ignore  # mypy cannot resolve the overloads:(
   1883     self,
   1884     path,
   1885     mode=mode,
   1886     format=format,
   1887     group=group,
   1888     engine=engine,
   1889     encoding=encoding,
   1890     unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims,
   1891     compute=compute,
   1892     multifile=False,
   1893     invalid_netcdf=invalid_netcdf,
   1894 )

File c:\Users\xxxxx\anaconda3\envs\weather_gen_3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py:1219, in to_netcdf(dataset, path_or_file, mode, format, group, engine, encoding, unlimited_dims, compute, multifile, invalid_netcdf)
...
    121     return arg

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in where(*args, **kwargs)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 19.2 GiB for an array with shape (210, 3500, 7000) and data type float32
```

## Environment

```py
windows 11 Home
xarray 2022.3.0
cfgrib 0.9.10.1
dask 2022.7.0
```

Comment: sorry - this is a giant wall of code. any chance you can reproduce the problem by just doing a single read & reindex operation? it's really your job to identify where and how the problem occurs and boil it down to a [mre] so we can help you decide where to go from there. I know that part is hard, but it's even more work for us to do than you - you know your code and data better than we do. most memory explosions in xarray boil down to unintended broadcasting or loading, so it should be reproducible in 2-3 lines. good luck!

Comment: also just keep in mind that dask is only scheduling operations (not executing them) until you trigger a blocking operation like write. so that (210, 3500, 7000) chunk may be occurring in an earlier step. if you have a chunk of that size, it doesn't help to rechunk it later - you need to avoid creating this chunk, because at some point a worker will have to get through this step. so step through the workflow and identify where your pain point is, paying attention to intermediate stages. it's likely not the write that's the problem.

Comment: Hey Michael - I agree there was way more than necessary there. I greatly simplified the script. I am now investigating whether there is an earlier step that's calling that huge chunk into memory and will follow up if I figure out what that is.

Comment: sounds great - thanks for the work to simplify it!

Answer (score 1):

A functional workaround is to chunk by a dimension that is unchanged during reindexing. The following modification causes the script to run successfully:

```py
ds = xr.open_dataset(
  fldr_in_grib,
  engine="cfgrib",
  chunks={ "latitude": 875 },
  backend_kwargs={ 'indexpath': '' }
)
```

Comment: yeah this is definitly a good pointer! if you have a dimension that is relatively unaffected by a workflow that's always a good one to chunk on, so that workers have access to the full array lengths when doing any broadcasting or reshaping on the other dims. Nice find!